# Odoo 11 eCommerce Delivery

Tags: odoo

Estoy trabajando con Odoo v11

Tengo el módulo eCommerce Delivery instalado y configurado pero en la tienda no se muestra el método de envío que he creado a la hora de pagar. En el total tampoco me suma el precio del envío.

El método de envío está activado y publicado.

¿A que se puede deber?

Comment: traduce tu pregunta al español, estas en SO en español de otra manera terminará cerrada

Comment: Está solucionado, no se a que se pudo deber, pero al reiniciar el servidor ya aparecen las opciones de envío.